# java instead of html,css and js in cordova projects

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, cordova

Is it possible to use java in place of **html, css and js in a cordova** project. If yes, will the **cordova** converts it to the android and ios app. Please give us some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. You can use a solution like [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) which allows you to build a mobile native application in Java.

You can [embed a Cordova app](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/phonegap-cordova-compatibility-for-codename-one.html) into a Codename One app too, but under the hood it is all Codename One.

Comment: Thanks @Shai, will you please say some  links to working example.

Comment: And will it able to convert it to web application with Codename One when written in java?

Comment: See http://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorials-resources-learn-java-mobile-videos-courses-ios-android.html Codename One's support for JavaScript targets is available in the enterprise tier so it's possible but not a part of the free offering.